# How to call only one ng-model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular, angularjs-ng-model

First of all, I just wanna say sorry for my confusing question. I really don't know what is the right title for my problem because I am new to angularjs. By the way, I am making a webportal using angularjs, and one of my webportal's functionality is to *post a feedback and reply a feedback*! When the visitor of the website will post a feedback, the admin will review it and comment to that feedback. For example, there are already 10 posts, so I am displaying it using the **mysql query**. Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblfb WHERE fb_status = 1 ORDER BY fb_id DESC";
...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
     echo "<h5>".$row['fb_sender']."</h5>
           <p>".$row['fb_content']."</p>
           <input type='text' ng-model='fbReply' id=".$row['fb_id'].">
          ";
}
```

In that code above, it works perfectly and it display all the post that has been approved, but I have a **problem** when typing a comment in the `fbRelpy model`. When I start to type, all the `textboxes` was filled with what I typed! What I mean is that, If I typed on the first textbox, it also apply the text in all textboxes. Maybe because they have all the `ng-model` value. What should I do? Thanks in advance. Please understand me about my **question title**.

Comment: Thats not right way to use angular.Use API call t get backenn stuff and then integrate it with html using angular.Otherwise it will create code which will be difficult to manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is all the inputs have same  models name. You have  give different model to differentiate between those. You can use `'fbReply{{'+$row['fb_id']+'}}'`   . The curly braces will make sure you get the inputs as object array.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblfb WHERE fb_status = 1 ORDER BY fb_id DESC";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
     echo "<h5>".$row['fb_sender']."</h5>
           <p>".$row['fb_content']."</p>
           <input type='text' ng-model='fbReply{{'+$row['fb_id']+'}}' id=".$row['fb_id'].">
          ";
}
```

Comment: welcome I would have appreciated if you called brother rather then sir :p @duterte

Comment: Hahaha sure brother! :D

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this issue because you're using a same ng-model for every comment input.

The possible solution will be attach a unique ng-model for every comment input. You can do that by using combination of your identifier and fb id. `ng-model='fbReply' + .$row['fb_id'].`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an array of ng-model you have to define you ng-model in you controller like this

```
 fbReplay ={}
```

And you code is something like below here

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblfb WHERE fb_status = 1 ORDER BY fb_id DESC";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
echo "<h5>".$row['fb_sender']."</h5><p>".$row['fb_content']."</p>
       <input type='text' ng-model='fbReply['+$row['fb_id']+']' id=".$row['fb_id'].">";
}
```

Comment: check answer as right please @duterte and give up vote